# Error while parsing the Tag Library Descriptor - Connect reset

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, taglib

When I tried to deploy my application, I get the errors as below:

```
<4/04/2012 03:24:08 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <developer> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] 
ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>>
 <> <> <1333517048130> <BEA-101196> <[/]: Error while parsing the Tag Library 
 Descriptor at "/opt/apps/domains/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/app-war.war/WEB-INF
/tlds/xkins.tld".
 com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset
```

The deployment can be done successfully but this error would make the process longer than normal.

I checked the tlds which have this problem, the dtd uris are:
http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd
http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd

But I can not access those two links via browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your using jsp2+ then we can use inbuilt taglibs.jsp2.0 provides jstl,displaytag taglibs in built.no need to put tlds in our web-inf.Other than these tag-libs then we have to do configuration in web.xml.